# My reverse proxy breaks wix nav bar with custom domain

Tags: javascript, reverse-proxy

I have a wix site with `native.example.com` set up in wix. But its actually hosted at `www.example.com/event` through a reverse proxy.

How do I fix the navigation buttons? so that they scroll down on the Single Page site instead of going somewhere random.

Answer (score 0):

Have the reverse proxy hasDomain from the metadata... which will change the warmup code to register the site as a non premium domain. and thus default to a 1 slug freesite. I found this using the profiler, pretty printing, base64 decoding and wit.

[image: hasdomain]